# Unable to use JSX in <script> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React.js.

Can someone please tell me why this is not working for me?

I created a basic html5 boilerplate and saved it as index.html. But when I open w/ browser, it says - **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>TITLE</title>
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

            <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
            <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
            <script>
                const Button = function () {
                    return (
                        <button>Go</button>
                    );
                };

                React.render((<Button/>), document.getElementById('example'));
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!--[if lte IE 9]>
                <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="https://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience and security.</p>
            <![endif]-->

            <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
            <p>Hello world! This is HTML5 Boilerplate.</p>

            <div id="example"></div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: <button>Go</button> is JSX so need to be parsed by babel  --  you should do this serverside,  but you can do in browser.   include babel cdn, and add type="text/babel" to your script tag

Comment: I added babel in script tag. Does that not suffice?

Comment: syntax errors are easily to fix by reading the error...

Comment: Start with https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html
You wont't require webpack and babel using create-react-app.

Comment: no, include babel cdn, https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation  or do on server

Comment: you will get performance issues if you are doing this in browser, but if its just to prototype, it's ok

Comment: If you want to start with React, I really liked the courses on https://www.codecademy.com/

Answer (score 2):

Getting back to your question, the problem that you are facing is that you are using wrong syntax, you are using JSX and in order to be able to actually use that you need `babel` to parse it.

To parse your code in the browser using Babel. Here its your code fixed with `babel` (also available on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZJQdg))

```html
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/babel">
            const Button = function () {
                return (
                    <button>Go</button>
                );
            };

            ReactDOM.render((<Button />), document.getElementById('example'));
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lte IE 9]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="https://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience and security.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <div id="example"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

What I would recommend you to check the [React Hello World Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html). It is a nice introduction to reactjs. The [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) will give you plenty of information how to get started.